# m3u8 Blank screen for video but the audio is playing ios 7.0

Tags: ios7, hlsl, m3u8

I know similar questions have been asked, but mine is a slight variation on the others and I haven't been able to track down a solution on my own yet.

I am streaming a m3u8 file through MPMoviePlayerController, following is my m3u8 content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=373120,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.66.30",RESOLUTION=320x180
sudan_tv-audio_und_102000_120%3D102000-video%3D250000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=744120,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.30",RESOLUTION=480x270
sudan_tv-audio_und_102000_120%3D102000-video%3D600000.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=108120,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
sudan_tv-audio_und_102000_120%3D102000.m3u8
```

On iOS7.1 it works fine BUT on iOS7.0 or iOS6.0.x I get only audio sometime I get black screen or first frame image.

Same wifi connection on both devices.

Is there known limitation about iOS7.0? I even tried to delete the last audio flavor with charles and still got the same result.

Will be happy to get your support,
Thanks,

Eliza